# How to create two separate login/register sections in Laravel 5

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-routing

How can I create user login/register pages and business login/register pages in Laravel 5. My AuthController uses:

```
use AuthenticatesAndRegistersUsers, ThrottlesLogins;
```

My routes.php is using:

```
Route::auth();
```

This is fine for user registration. How can I add a seperate registration for another entity that is different from the user?

Comment: If you're using 5.2, you can look at https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/authentication#authentication-quickstart, in particular `php artisan make:auth`

Comment: Yes, I did that. That's fine for user registration, but not for registering another entity.

Answer (score 1):

You can specify different routes to different controllers and/or actions.

Example:

```
Route::auth();
$this->get('b_login', 'Auth\AuthController@showBusinessLoginForm');
$this->post('b_login', 'Auth\AuthController@businessLogin');
```

Now you can implement the business login actions in your `Auth\AuthController`.

**Edit**

I noticed it is simpler to use a second controller for the business register/login actions. Than you can use the `AuthenticatesAndRegistersUsers` trait in each controller. That means you only have to override the actions that you want to adapt.

Could look similar like this:

routes.php

```
Route::auth();
$this->get('b_login', 'Auth\BusinessAuthController@showLoginForm');
$this->post('b_login', 'Auth\BusinessAuthController@login');
```

Auth/AuthController.php

```
...
use AuthenticatesAndRegistersUsers;

protected $redirectPath = '/home';

// do some other stuff
...
```

Auth/BusinessAuthController.php

```
...
use AuthenticatesAndRegistersUsers;

protected $redirectPath = '/home-business';

// for checking $user->is_business_user == 1 while attemping login
protected function getCredentials(Request $request){
    $credentials = $request->only($this->loginUsername(), 'password');
    $credentials['is_business_user'] = 1;
    return $credentials;
}

// do some other stuff
...
```

Comment: Yes, thanks, I've done that. How would I go about building those methods in the controller? Do I take the code from the trait RegistersUsers?